# How is the order in a "foreach" determined?

Tags: c#, foreach

I was wondering what determines the order in a foreach loop?

For example, I have a loop that removes any '*' characters from a label:

```
foreach (Label lbl in Form.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    lbl.Text = lbl.Text.TrimEnd('*');
}
```

Is there a way to determine what the order is for the labels as it steps through the collection?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280497/order-of-controls-in-a-forms-control-property-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @stuartd I can't see a `List<T>` being looped over in this question...

Comment: @spender The answer covers the general case, regardless of the title of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach` uses whatever order the `IEnumerable` that was given to it was ordered, so it is up to `Form.Controls` on what the order is. The order is whatever order the autogenerated code in your `.designer.cs` file decided to generate in.

If you want to enforce a order you need to sort the `IEnumerable` before you give it to the `foreach`. For example, the below code will sort them by control name.

```
foreach (Label lbl in Form.Controls.OfType<Label>().OrderBy(x=>x.Name)
{
    lbl.Text = lbl.Text.TrimEnd('*');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the order, you just need to order the list. For example, this code is verbose but demonstrates usage of `OrderBy`:

```
var labels = Form.Controls.OfType<Label>();
var orderLabels = labels.OrderBy(l => l.Text);

foreach (Label lbl in orderedLabels)
{
    lbl.Text = lbl.Text.TrimEnd('*');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the order of the `Controls` collection. It will first look for all controls that are of type `Label` and them lets say in an array.

So it will start from 0 to 1 to n, and the `foreach` would start at the index 0.

If you want to specify it's order you can use Linq extension methods namely `OrderBy`

MSDN for OrderBy: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx)