# how i can be using for each control and adding it to Tuple (of Label))

Tags: vb.net

how i can be using `for each control` and adding it to `Tuple (of Label))`

the error I get

*( Value of type 'Tuple(Of Control)' cannot be converted to 'Tuple(Of Label))*

This is my Code

```
Private first As List(Of Tuple(Of Label))

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    first = New List(Of Tuple(Of Label))
    For Each cntl As Control In Controls
        first.Add(Tuple.Create(cntl))
    next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use a Tuple with only one item? Also, direct to the question... _You can't_, because not all controls are Labels.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am using that for a loop and every label will get info from  every line a Text File dynamically

Comment: Then why a Tuple and not just a List?  You should probably be using a ListBox instead of a bunch of Labels.

Comment: no there will be event Handler for each label that's why it must be labels but there is another proplem

Comment: Why someone down vote my question there is nothing wrong with my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control.OfType(Of Label)` filters out non-labels

And use a `Label` as your loop variable

```
Private first As List(Of Tuple(Of Label))

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    first = New List(Of Tuple(Of Label))
    For Each cntl As Label In Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
        first.Add(Tuple.Create(cntl))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx do u know by any chance why when I read lines from text file and assign that to labels it goes backward ?

Comment: I guess it has to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280513/832052)

Answer (score 0):

If your list needs to remain a `Tuple(Of Label)` then you'll need to cast the control to a `Label`. You can achieve this with `Dim convertedControl = cntl as Label`

Otherwise, the original Tuple can be defined as `Tuple(Of Control)` if they don't *have* to be labels

Comment: We know that in addition to the `Labels`, there is at least a button, `Button1`. `Me.Controls` will return that as well (and fit into `Tuple(Of Control)` just fine).